# Provide Mods a Button to Toggle-Off Mod Powers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

["We preach admins having separate tiers of ability. Mods should as well. Should be a 'hammer' toggle button"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2024876#2024876)

While it may not be an issue that mods on larger sites find relevant, I believe that mods on smaller sites have a keener interest in sometimes acting as part of a community and steering consensus. There are cases where one as an individual may express the belief that a question ought to be closed as off-topic without feeling the certainty or need to immediately nuke it.

```
-if (is_moderator)
+if (is_moderator && hammer_time)
```

Added bonus: mods save time involving personal conflict and users are possibly more understanding when five people close their question.

Comment: I can see the benefit in having that feature for the unilateral close question tool.

Comment: To clarify - quite often I may think that a question or answer may need a vote to close, but I won't do it, as mod vote to close wins instantly. Current workaround is to discuss in chat and wait, which works but is a bit limiting sometimes.

Comment: This issue has been brought up and rejected several times on MSO, which is probably where this question should be (if it should be at all).

Comment: I agree with the idea, but as @Iszi mentioned this was brought up and rejected several times. That said, there is no problem with raising and requesting it here again... *Especially* here, since this isn't just a usability issue, it is a *privilege management* issue - which falls squarely in the domain of [security.se] :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several good answers here:

[Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote)

Generally our philosophy is

1. Leave copious comments to instruct if you don't want to vote as a mod. This is good and excellent and encouraged at all times. It is far better than voting. Use your moderator words!
2. Moderators should be bold, and vote as they see fit to lead and guide their communities. Hesitating under the guise of "aw shucks, I'm just a reg'lar user like you folks" is not a moderator strategy we encourage.