# A moderator is harassing me. Someone please look at this

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Information Security Stack Exchange post: [What’s the best way to report an IP address from Romania?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206084/what-s-the-best-way-to-report-an-ip-address-from-romania/206088#206088)

The mod that deleted my answer is mad at me because I told him he marked something as off topic that was not off topic in a different post. He is just seeking retribution.

Comment: I am not seeking retribution. Your answer had no bearing on the question. It was a non-answer.

Comment: That is up to the asker.

Comment: I really doubt @schroeder is mad at you about this, more likely he feels bad for you. You walked in to a new site like a bull in a china shop - we try very hard to be welcoming to newcomers but you need to take a moment to see how the site works, and its not as you would want it to. Schroeder was correct that the question was offtopic, and he is right that your answer does not apply in any way to the question that was asked (it was not even wrong, it was just irrelevant).

Comment: His own words in the comments of the off topic bad usb post were that asking about a specific device is ok and I did exactly that.

Comment: In the email thread, I said "if it is spam" he went after me specifically then. If it's not spam the asker can follow a different route, but if it is spam which there is a significant chance the answer would help.

Comment: I am not a moderator (on this site) but just a high-rep user who has been a member since day one, and @schroeder's action was the correct one.  You misunderstood the question and your answers were not applicable and should indeed have been deleted to reduce the amount of noise on the site.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand the question. Someone got an unwanted email. I told them how to deal with that, if it was spam. If it isn't they dont have to follow it.

Comment: "If it was spam" - it clearly was not, and spam-related comments are explicitly unrelated to the question. "I burnt my steak" - "well if it was an apple pie" < it's not, why are we talking about pie?

Comment: How can you say it was clearly not? It was an email the poster did not want. Literally anyone but you guys considers that spam. Also, @schroeder told the other person who answered that his answer may have missed the mark, but he didn't delete it. I was the only one deleted even though he raised the same issue with both posts. Its not hard to see that is targeting me.

Comment: Bluntly, I consider you wrong. Several hours of the collective time of the moderators and a few other high rep users have gone into this discussion with you. It's simply not worth that much time. Let it go, spend some time working on the areas you don't see (consider that there are many contexts for this to not be "spam"), and work on improving. If you keep on the same way, one of us will end up suspending your account, and all of us will back the decision.

Comment: I never said that there isn't some way it may not be spam, but that doesn't mean its for sure not spam, again, he let the other post that he had raised issue with go. Why only delete mine?

Comment: @user197001 The email was *not* spam.  The email body contained an IP address.  He wanted to report the IP address that was in the email.  Not report the email.  Not report the IP address the email came from.  The IP address the authentication attempt came from, which was in the email.

Comment: As to the other answer, it's questionable advice. That is what the comment identifies.  Your answer was not questionable advice. It was not even bad or wrong advice.  It was irrelevant advice on a different topic entirely.

Answer (score 13):

You are not being harassed. The actions taken are not long enough to constitute a pattern, I highly doubt it was via looking at your profile, and these actions are exactly in the scope of a moderator's job. Setting a floor for the quality of questions and answers on this site is the responsibility of moderators. Working to help you, if you're in a place to seek help and listen to constructive criticism, is also our role.

It is not the asker's job to police answers, it is the community of the site. Users vote answers up and down, and those with enough history in the site are also trusted to vote to delete. Moderators are entrusted based on their history within the site, and the vote of the community, to also act upon those... with tools that react more quickly.

You are due some introspection on what makes a good quality post, why you've fallen short of it thus far, and how this post is contradictory to improving your ability to be a useful part of this or any other functional community.

Comment: @user197001 please note this is the THIRD moderator, the most trusted users on this site, to inform you that your aggressive behavior is in the wrong. Please take a moment to understand how this community works, then come back and join us as a productive member of this community.

Comment: He does not follow what he has said. He said asking about a specific device is ok. I did that in the post labeled as off topic.

Comment: Its not the asker's job to police it as in you should delete an answer if it is abusive or something like that, but if there is a chance it could be what the asker needs, the asker is allowed to pick the answer he or she likes.

Comment: @jeffferland he didn't delete the other answer even though he said that one may be wrong bc the answerer couldn't show proof that the email was abusive. Why is it ok for that poster to maybe be wrong and maybe be right, but its not ok for me?

Comment: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/provide-mods-a-button-to-toggle-off-mod-powers - we don't get to go light when we point something out. There also isn't a "close answer" button, only a close question. Non-answers are directly deleted.

Comment: And to clarify: if it was simply a wrong answer, we would have left it to rot. An irrelevant answer that is not related to the question simply gunks up the site.

Comment: I get what you are saying if it were an irrelavent answer, but he said the same thing about the other answer and he left it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm normally the first person to complain about moderator abuse, but the moderators on this site are honestly very good. They weren't "punishing you", just deleting an answer. This is not uncommon on Stack Exchange. In fact, it is expected. Think of it more like Wikipedia, where it is a collection of useful knowledge rather than a bunch of privately-owned posts. If an answer needs editing, a moderator or even someone random will edit it. If an answer is not appropriate for whatever reason, a moderator can delete it. It's not an attack against *you*, and while I am not a mind reader, I am pretty sure that none of the moderators here are *mad* at you. They deal with this every day in the constant battle to ensure quality.

Your responses have been pretty aggressive from what I've seen, and I don't blame you. You were likely under the belief that, like many social media sites, posts are only deleted under extreme circumstances and only when the poster has done something *really bad*. That is not the case here. We have a very high standard for answers and, even if your answer may have been totally acceptable elsewhere, it wasn't acceptable here. Many new users go through the process of submitting a question or answer and having it closed or deleted, and that's not a bad thing. Just learn from it; no one will hold anything against you!